# Formula matemática a la inversa en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Buenas colegas les formulo mi duda:
Estoy haciendo una calculadora para calcular(valgame la redundancia) las comisiones de paypal, hasta este punto todo bien, ahora la duda es como puedo hacer esa formula pero a la inversa, osea que yo le ponga cuanto quiero recibir y me ponga cuanto me tienen que enviar, las calculadoras que hay en Internet no me sirven porque no toman en cuenta el IVA(16%), se hacer todo para saber cuanto me va a llegar dependiendo de la cantidad que envié, pero no me sale hacerlo a la inversa, esto es mas bien un problema matemático.

les anexo el código de la calculadora haber si alguien sabe como hacerlo a la inversa.

```js
function calcularRecibe() {
        let seEnvia = parseFloat(document.getElementById('se_envia').value),
            comision = document.getElementById('comision'),
            comisionIva = document.getElementById('comision_iva'),
            serecibe = document.getElementById('se_recibe');

        comision.value = (seEnvia * 0.0395) + 4;
        comision_iva.value = parseFloat(comision.value) * 1.16;
        serecibe.value = seEnvia - parseFloat(comision_iva.value);
    }
```

```html
<div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        Calculadora de paypal
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <!-- Default input -->
                            <label for="se_envia" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Se envia</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="se_envia" placeholder="00" onkeyup="calcularRecibe()">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Grid row -->

                        <!-- Grid row -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <!-- Default input -->
                            <label for="comision" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Comision</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comision" placeholder="00" readonly>
                                <small>3.95%+4</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Grid row -->

                        <!-- Grid row -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <!-- Default input -->
                            <label for="comision_iva" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Comision</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comision_iva" placeholder="00" readonly>
                                <small>Comision mas el 16% de IVA</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Grid row -->

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <!-- Default input -->
                            <label for="se_recibe" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Se recibe</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="se_recibe" placeholder="00" readonly>
                                <small>Comision mas iva sumado al monto enviado</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Grid row -->


                    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución está en realizar el despeje de la cantidad que se envía, dada la cantidad que se recibe. Luego, se calculan la comisión y la comisión + iva.

**PROBLEMA**

Dada una fórmula de cálculo de comisión y comisión + iva, se calcula el monto final recibido teniendo el monto enviado. Se desea realizar la operación inversa, es decir, dada la cantidad enviada, calcular la cantidad recibida y calcular los montos de comisión y comisión + iva.

**SOLUCION**

La solución se obtiene despejando la cantidad enviada de la fórmula de cantidad recibida, de la siguiente manera:

```
// Esta es la fórmula de la cantidad recibida
seRecibe = seEnvia - comision_iva // (1)

// Despejamos seEnvia
seEnvia = seRecibe + comision_iva // (2)

// Esta es la fórmula de comision_iva
comision_iva = comision * 1.16 // (3)

// Sustituimos comision_iva en la formula de seEnvia (3 en 2)
seEnvia = seRecibe + (comision * 1.16) // (4)

//Esta es la fórmula de comision
comision = (seEnvia * 0.0395) + 4 // (5)

// Sustituimos comision en la formula de seEnvia (5 en 4) 
seEnvia = seRecibe + ((seEnvia * 0.0395) + 4) * 1.16 // (6)

// Realizamos las operaciones, ya tenemos solo las 2 cantidades que nos interesan
seEnvia = seRecibe + ((seEnvia * 0.0395) * 1.16) + 4.64
seEnvia = seRecibe + (seEnvia * 0.04582) + 4.64
seEnvia - (seEnvia * 0.04582) = seRecibe + 4.64
seEnvia * (1 - 0.04582) = seRecibe + 4.64
seEnvia = (seRecibe + 4.64)/0.95418 // (7)
```

Asi, la fórmula (7) es la que usaremos para calcular la cantidad seEnvia. Luego, al obtener la cantidad seEnvia, podemos calcular comision y comision_iva, usando las fórmulas (5) y (3) respectivamente.

El resultado sería el siguiente:

```js
    function calcularEnvio() {
        let seRecibe = parseFloat(document.getElementById('se_recibe_2').value),
            comision = document.getElementById('comision_2'),
            comision_iva = document.getElementById('comision_iva_2'),
            seEnvia = document.getElementById('se_envia_2');

        seEnvia.value = parseFloat((seRecibe + 4.64) / 0.95418).toFixed(4);
        comision.value = parseFloat(((seEnvia.value) * 0.0395) + 4).toFixed(4);
        comision_iva.value = parseFloat((comision.value) * 1.16).toFixed(4);
    }
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
    Calculadora de paypal
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="form-group row">
      <!-- Default input -->
        <label for="se_recibe_2" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Se recibe</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="se_recibe_2" placeholder="00" onkeyup="calcularEnvio()">
          <small>Comision mas iva sumado al monto enviado</small>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="form-group row">
      <!-- Default input -->
        <label for="comision_2" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Comision</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comision_2" placeholder="00" readonly>
          <small>3.95%+4</small>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="form-group row">
      <!-- Default input -->
        <label for="comision_iva_2" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Comision</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comision_iva_2" placeholder="00" readonly>
          <small>Comision mas el 16% de IVA</small>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="form-group row">
      <!-- Default input -->
        <label for="se_envia_2" class="col-md-4 col-form-label">Se envia</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="se_envia_2" placeholder="00" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
```

He utilizado el método `toFixed()` para redondear los decimales, generalmente para transacciones monetarias se realiza el redondeo de 4 dígitos decimales. Eso ya lo decides tu de acuerdo a tus requerimientos.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, ya llevaba un buen rato tratando de hacer la formula a la inversa, inclusive en excel y no me salia, tu respuesta fue excelente. gracias muchas gracias.